# How to recursively look at the files from a directory, remove specific pattern and write it to a new filename at the same hierarchy

Tags: linux, shell, file, grep

There are files for example `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt` at different hierarchical level in a directory.

`a.txt` content is

```
apple  
orange  
mango
```

`b.txt` content is

```
grape  
apple  
mango
```

`c.txt` content is

```
orange  
mango  
apple  
grape
```

Now apple should be removed from all the files and need to save the files with new names `a_1.txt`, `b_1.txt`, `c_1.txt` at the same places keeping the original files also at the same places.

So that `a_1.txt` content should be

```
orange  
mango
```

`b_1.txt` content should be

```
grape  
mango
```

`c_1.txt should be

```
orange  
mango  
grape
```

Comment: Welcome to *Stack Overflow*. Please edit your question and let us know what you have tried so far by posting some code.  Show us where you are getting stuck. Contrary to popular belief, *Stack Overflow* is not a site where you dump your coding requests and go enjoy your day while someone codes your requirement. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`shell`** solution (with combination of `grep` + `sed` + `prename`(*Perl* *`rename`*) tools):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c \
'grep -q "\<apple" "$0" && (sed -i "/\<apple/d" "$0"; prename "s/\.txt$/_1$&/" "$0" )' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope these commands will help in your script.

```
$ sed -i -e 's/apple//g' *.txt

$ for f in *.txt; do printf '%s\n' "${f%.txt}_1.txt"; done
```